# Open multiple terminal windows from single program in Golang

Tags: go, command-line-interface, goroutine, channel

**Usecase**

I am making an app that makes use of a command line interface.

In one terminal window, non-static information should be displayed to the user.

In the other terminal window it should display logs to the user, as well as allowing them to interact with it.

My thinking is that I could then use channels to send information between the go routines that each terminal window runs on.

**Question**

Is it possible to open more than one terminal window at a time with Golang? If not, are there any alternatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can write a frontend to show the commands and communicate with the backend through HTTP API.